# Gerundios con verbos de percepción: ¿es correcto «sentía un dedo tocando su piel»?

Tags: gramática, gerundio

Estaba pensando en la frase (por ejemplo):

> 1) Sentía un dedo tocando su piel.

y no sabía si fuera mejor así:

> 2) Sentía un dedo que tocaba su piel.

Para mí la frase 1 no es correcta, porque en esta se usa el gerundio de manera adjetival, lo que, a mi entender, no está permitido. Sin embargo sé que con verbos de percepción este uso sí está permitido:

> Miró a las chicas entrando en la sala.

Entonces, ¿es la frase 1 correcta? Si es correcta, ¿es correcta porque el verbo es de percepción?

Answer (score 2):

*Sentir* es un verbo de percepción en el ejemplo dado (equivale a *percibir de manera táctil*), por lo cual el uso del gerundio es correcto 
en este caso, ya que está cubierto por la regla que mencionas. Más allá de eso, se trata de un **gerundio predicativo** como el descripto en la NGLE ([27.1p](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=beSPcKZRSCaapUrz)):

[image: NGLE 27.1p]

El complemento expresado por el gerundio puede atribuirse al sujeto, al objeto directo (*un dedo* en el ejemplo) y a ciertos otros complementos. Este uso es bastante más amplio que el de los verbos de percepción, al cual incluye.

Comment: Gracias-  por cierto, con respecto a la cita de la NGLE: ¿vale la pena comprar la NGLE Manual?  No puedo permitirme la colección de dos tomos en este momento, por tanto pienso en comprar la edición condensada, pero no sé si le falta demasiado para ser útil.

Comment: No sabría decirte, ya que nunca he tenido en mis manos la NGLE en ninguna de sus versiones. Sólo la consulto vía web, que por cierto es bastante poco amigable...

Comment: Me encanta mi NGLE Manual. La leo cual novela para adormecerme. xD

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto debería ser un comentario mas que una respuesta.

Mientras que la 1) me parece correcta, la 2) me parece incorrecta.

Sentir es una percepción muy vaga que no te puede dar la noción especifica de un dedo de un evento tan impreciso.

La frase quedaría mejor con "vio" en lugar de "sintió", eliminando la ambigüedad.

Incluso sonaría mejor cambiando el "que" antes del "un", cambiando el sentido de la oración:

> Vió un dedo que tocaba su piel.
>   Sintió que un dedo tocaba su piel.

Comment: Compara: *Sentía el avance lento y paciente del dedo cálido trazando círculos por la espalda.*

Comment: por todas partes veo diptongos monosílabos acentuados y no acentuados, haciendo un poquito de investigación tal parece que la regla ortográfica desde hace mas de 50 años es "no acentuarlos".